# Angularjs filter not null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Trying to filter out items with a certain property that is not null So for:

```
var details = [{name:'Bill', shortDescription: null}, {name:'Sally', shortDescription: 'A girl'}]
```

I would like to only show one li; the one for sally. This is what I have tried with no success

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription:'!'}">
<p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how I can do this without creating a custom filter? Or even so, what the custom filter would look like?

Comment: Different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992197/257470

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11573 for Angular >= 1.4, the recommendation is to use '' which matches any primitive except null/undefined.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: ''}">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting!

Comment: Works, thanks. But in this case the angularjs syntax is absurd (filter--).

Comment: @MCurbelo, my own pet peeve with the filter syntax is that the word "filter" is ambiguous.  Are filtering *for* null descriptions?  Or filtering *out* null descriptions?  You can't tell from looking at the code.  A better name would be "filterOut" or "showOnly" (with proper semantics).

Answer (score 125):

Angular >=1.3.16 to latest (1.5.5 at time of writing/update) use `''` (empty string) (or `'!!'` also works)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: ''}">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/1mnachk6/

---

Angular >=1.3.6 and <=1.3.15 use `'!null'`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: '!null'}">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/4wxs67yv/

---

Angular >=1.2 and <=1.3.5 use `''` (empty string) (or `'!!'` also works)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: ''}">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/ovsqf17n/

---

Angular <1.2 `'!!'`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: '!!'}">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/RGEdc/

---

Overall, `'!!'` has the best support, but [`''` (empty string) is recommended and intended for this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11573#issuecomment-109975917).

Comment: Thanks so much. Searched the web for over an hour and couldn't find that

Comment: No problem.  It also filters out `undefined`.

Comment: @TalasanNicholson if it's filtering on null/undefined then false would be ok.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne is this documented?

Comment: This does not seem to work with a checkbox `value="!!"` http://jsfiddle.net/2RBV9/

Comment: @sylouuu, `null` is a reserved word, you cannot name your model `null`.  Also, your checkbox was out of the scope of the controller. Lastly, you would need to use the `ngTrueValue` attribute to set the model value with a checkbox https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D Here is the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2RBV9/1/

Comment: Thx @TheSharpieOne, I had to put `ng-true-value="!"` and `ng-false-value="!!"`

Comment: This trick doesn't seem to work in 1.4.0-rc1.  I've been looking for a change note for a new syntax but haven't found anything so far.

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/a50kdaL0/

Comment: if list shortDescription is an object and return null for some "detail" FOR EXAMPLE detail[0].shortDescription:null and for some detail[1].shortDescription: {id:1}, user can filter to get not null objects only,,, by filter : {shortDescription: {} } it will show only detail[1].shortDescription object only.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is easier to read

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in details" ng-if="detail.shortDescription">
        <p>{{detail.shortDescription}}</p>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: there are tons of solution about filtering null values, this is the one I prefer

Comment: A disadvantage to this is if you have a thousand records, it still prints as many comment tags as there are records which don't have short descriptions. The filter option prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that to use the empty quotes solution,  you need to leave the comparator at its default of `false`. You maybe be used to putting true in here in your controller filters, like this :

```
const myAssessments = 
       this.filterFilter(this.assessments, {userId: this.user.id}, true);
```

That type of strict filter wouldn't work without the final `true`. But you need to drop the true or make it false for a not null check to work :

```
const activeAndHistoric = 
      this.filterFilter(filteredAssessments, {historicYear: ''}, false);
```