# ng-repeat custom filter generates infinite loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm iterating over a list of pages/articles. I want to remove pages that don't have an article id from the list (they are section front pages). I have made a custom filter to determine if the article has an id or not ('removeFrontpages'), but it's generating an infinite loop (list is loaded over and over again). When I remove the filter, the list is loaded once.

I'm not moderating the objects in the list, simply filtering out some articles. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to make a filter on ng-repeat or should I filter the list before (in the service/controller)?

This is my filter:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("app")
    .filter('removeFrontpages', [function() {
        return function (articles) {
            var filtered = [];

            if (typeof articles !== "undefined") {

                angular.forEach(articles, function (article) {

                    if (typeof article.id !== "undefined" && article.id !== "") {
                        filtered.push(article);
                    }

                });
            }
            return filtered;
        };

    }]);
```

My directive template looks like this:

```
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1 header-visits"><h4><a ng-click="reorder('stats.people');">Besøg</a></h4></div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 header-title"><h4><a ng-click="reorder('title');">Titel</a></h4></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 header-engagedtime"><h4><a ng-click="reorder('stats.engaged_time.avg');">Tid</a></h4></div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="article in articles | removeFrontpages | orderBy: orderBy:isReverseOrder | limitTo: limit track by article.id" index-class>

    <!-- index -->
    <div class="col-xs-1 list-index">
        {{ $index+1 }}
    </div>

    <!-- visits -->
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span class="stats-text">{{ article.stats.people }}</span>
    </div>

    <!-- title -->
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <a href="http://{{article.path}}" target="_blank" class="article-title">{{ article.title }}</a>

        <div class="row" ng-if="dashboardType != 'top articles from social media'">
            <div class="col-xs-12 article-stats">

                <div class="pull-left article-mobile">
                    <i class="fa fa-mobile dark-grey"></i>
                    <span class="stats-text">{{ article.stats.platform.m }}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-link dark-grey"></i>
                    <span class="stats-text">{{ article.stats.links }}</span>
                </div>

                <div class="pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o dark-grey"></i>
                    <span class="stats-text">{{ article.publishDate | date: 'dd/MM hh:mm'}}</span>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- end col-xs-12 -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->

        <div class="row" ng-if="dashboardType == 'top articles from social media'">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <progressbar class=""
                             max="1"
                             value="(article.stats.social/ article.stats.count)"
                             type="info">
                    <span class="progressbar-text">
                        {{ (article.stats.social / article.stats.count) * 100 | number:0 }}%
                    </span>
                </progressbar>

            </div> <!-- end col-xs-12 -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div>

    <!-- engaged time -->
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span class="stats-text" ng-if="article.engaged_time.avg >= 0">{{ article.engaged_time.avg | secsToMMSS }}</span>
        <span class="stats-text" ng-if="article.stats.engaged_time >= 0">{{ article.stats.engaged_time | secsToMMSS }}</span>
        <span class="stats-text" ng-if="article.stats.engaged_time.avg >= 0">{{ article.stats.engaged_time.avg | secsToMMSS }}</span>
    </div>

</div> <!-- end article -->
```

Comment: If you are trying to filter out undefined, you can use the provided `filter` filter and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18644490/1873485

Comment: Ok great tip, thanks! But unfortunately it does not explain the infinite loop in my code. Also the ids are never null or undefined but strings (no id is an empty string)

Comment: Sorry, it appeared that you were trying to filter those things out with `typeof article.id !== "undefined" && article.id !== ""`.  Since they can never be that thing, I am lost as to what you are trying to do with your custom filter.  I would suggest just removing the custom filer and the double `orderBy` and see if it works.

Comment: 1. You're right! The if-check should just be article.id !== "". 
2. It's not a double orderby! The second "orderBy" is a scope variable named "orderBy"!