# AngularJS-Filters no filter empty attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when the attribute of the object does not exist and I can not filter using  `"!null"`, I wonder if filter can validate this or i need to create a new filter for this.

Html `ng-repeat`

```
 <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: '!null'}">
    <p>{{detail.name}}</p>
 </li>
```

JavaScript `Array`

```
$scope.details = [{
        name: 'Bill',
        shortDescription: null
    },{
        name: 'Bill2',
    }, {
        name: 'Sally',
        shortDescription: 'A girl'
    }];
```

Result

- Bill2
- Sally

Bill2 have no exist `shortDescription` but not filter.

expected Result:

- Sally

JSFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/4wxs67yv/28/

AngularJS `v.1.3.15`

How i can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs filter not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644412/angularjs-filter-not-null)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using double not operator,as

```
<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: '!!'}">
<p>{{detail.name}}</p>
```

Comment: could you update the fiddle with answer http://jsfiddle.net/4wxs67yv/30/ ..its not working here

Comment: i want filter but when no exists attribute : result = *Sally