# Angularjs filter not null for an object in Select ng-options:

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter out items which are objects & not `null` in angular 1.5.6.

I tried all options from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644412/angularjs-filter-not-null).

Still cannot make it to work.

Only 'Sally' should be shown in the `select`

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp84op9g/3/)

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <br>

     <select ng-model="a" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details | filter:{shortDescription:'!null'} track by detail.name">
  </select>

    <br>
    New 

     <select ng-model="b" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: ''} track by detail.name">
  </select>

    <br>
    All
    <select  ng-model="c" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details | filter:{shortDescription: '!!'} track by detail.name">
  </select>

  <br>
  Without any filter
  <select ng-model="d" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details track by detail.name">
  </select>
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{
        name: 'Bill',
        shortDescription: null
    }, {
        name: 'Sally',
        shortDescription: {'MyName':'A girl'}
    }];
}

angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `filter:{shortDescription: ''}` matches only primitives but not complex objects and `shortDescription` in your case is a nested object.
Therefore instead use `filter:{shortDescription:{$:''}}` like so:

```
  <select ng-model="a" 
          ng-options="detail.name for detail in details | filter:{shortDescription:{$:''}} track by detail.name">
  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please run this snippet to achieve your goal

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{
        name: 'Bill',
        shortDescription: null
    }, {
        name: 'Sally',
        shortDescription: {'MyName':'A girl'}
    }];

}

angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl", myCtrl).filter('descFilter',descFilter);

function descFilter(){
 return function(array,key){
   var newArr = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     if (array[i][key] != null){
       newArr.push(array[i]);
      }
    }
    return newArr;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <br>
     With Filter:
     <select ng-model="a" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details | descFilter:'shortDescription'">
  </select>
    
  
  <br>
  Without any filter
  <select ng-model="d" ng-options="detail.name for detail in details track by detail.name">
  </select>
  <!-- -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Your answer indeed works. but that would mean creating a new array inside & another filter function. I was looking for something basic like what DAXholic provided.

Answer (score 1):

In ngOptions the not null check is know to not work. Instead you can create a custom filter and use that.

Here is an example with a custom filter function.
http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/bue59Loj/

The custom filter function:

```
$scope.isDescriptionNull = function(item) {
            if (item.shortDescription === null) return false;

          return true;
        }
```

And how to use it:

```
<select ng-model="a" ng-options="detail.name for detail in (details | filter:isDescriptionNull) track by detail.name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a little bug in your markup.

The filter expects to get a object property, expression, or comparator.

Official documentation:

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator : anyPropertyKey}}
```

So, what you are doing isn't a valid filter

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="a" 
          ng-options="detail.name for detail in details  | filter:{shortDescription:'!!'}} track by detail.name">
  </select>
```