# How to tell Angular not to present a null option?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options

I have the following line that creates a select box:

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedConfig" ng-options="config as config.name for config in configs"></select>
```

The problem is that this box also presents one null option. 
[image]

My question is how to make ng-options present only the options that are not null?

Comment: Angular automatically adds that when the `ng-model` does not match any of the options. It will be removed as soon as an option is selected. If you don't want it to show up then you have to set the default value of `selectedConfig` to one of your `config` items.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer :**
Define a value for selectedConfig :

```
$scope.selectedConfig = $scope.configs[0] ;
```

**Old answer :**
You can add a filter !

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedConfig" ng-options="config as config.name for config in configs | filter:{name: ''}"></select>
```

See : [Angularjs filter not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644412/angularjs-filter-not-null)

Comment: How is that going to remove the empty option that is automatically added to the `<select>` when the `ng-model` value does not match any of the options?

Comment: Your selectedConfig is set to configs[0] ?