# angular filter without using angular function

Tags: angularjs, filter

What I want to do is to create 2 angular tables where I display tasks. In the first table I want to show all tasks which are not assigned to user and in the second tab I want to show all tasks which are assigned to user

`UsersDTO` is array, I may have more users assigned to the same task.

My html code looks like this. This is tab where I got all tasks with assigned user to it. I am not pretty sure why this is working, but I assume it somehow looks into property and check if there is anything.

[image]

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in project.ProjectTasksDTO | filter: {UsersDTO: {}}">
         <td>{{task.Id}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Title}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Text}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Description}}</td>
         <td><p ng-repeat="user in task.UsersDTO">{{user.UserName}}</p></td>
         <td>{{task.Status}}</td>                                                  
         <td>{{task.CreatedBy}}</td>
         <td><button class="btn-info" ng-click="editUser(user);">Profile</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is there a way how to tell to filter in `ng-repeat` that `UsersDTO` is null or empty, something  like in code below.

[image]

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in project.ProjectTasksDTO | filter: {UsersDTO: {null}}">
         <td>{{task.Id}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Title}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Text}}</td>
         <td>{{task.Description}}</td>
         <td><p ng-repeat="user in task.UsersDTO">{{user.UserName}}</p></td>
         <td>{{task.Status}}</td>                                                  
         <td>{{task.CreatedBy}}</td>
         <td><button class="btn-info" ng-click="editUser(user);">Profile</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Not sure if this can be done without a custom filter function - any reason why you wouldn't use one?

Comment: I have no specific reason for it, but i was curious if something like this could be done with ng-repeat filter

Comment: Could you check this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644412/angularjs-filter-not-null

Comment: @Everton Santos Thats exactly what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Martin you're welcome.. I needed it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do it this way without a the need for a function.

```
<div ng-repeat="task in project.ProjectTasksDTO | filter:{UsersDTO.length: 0}:true">

<div ng-repeat="task in project.ProjectTasksDTO | filter:{UsersDTO.length: 0}:false">
```

Altough keep in mind that the :true and :false notation is actually an angular specific shorthand notation and will be replaced with function(actual,expected) in a literal comparison to see if these match yes:true or no:false

[Fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6ubxna0/)

Comment: Hi, this looks also like a very nice solution for this, but it throws me a syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 39 of the expression [project.ProjectTasksDTO | filter:{task.UsersDTO.length: 0}:true] starting at [.UsersDTO.length: 0}:true].

Comment: Are you sure its not deprecated? Anytime i use dot in expression it just throw an error. I solved this already with using ng-if, something like this:


<tr ng-repeat="task in project.ProjectTasksDTO" ng-if="task.UsersDTO != null">

 but i had to do extra modifications on my server side to send null to my objects when they are empty

Comment: @Martin I added a plunkr to clarify